# Zend_Gdata NicknamesFeed - how to access userName property in php

Tags: php, zend-framework

The retrieveAllNicknames() function in the Gapps class (pertaining to the Google Provisioning API) returns elements that look like this:

```
  <atom:entry>
    <atom:id>
        https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/example.com/nickname/2.0/suse
    </atom:id>
    <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
        term="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006#nickname"/>
    <atom:title type="text">suse</atom:title>
    <atom:link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"
        href="https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/example.com/nickname/2.0/suse"/>
    <atom:link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"
        href="https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/example.com/nickname/2.0/suse"/>
    <apps:nickname name="suse"/>
    <apps:login userName="SusanJones"/>
</atom:entry>
```

I can write a loop that gets the value of the nickname element like so:

```
$nicknames = $service->retrieveAllNicknames();
foreach ($nicknames->entries as $entry) {
    echo "<p>". $entry->nickname."</p>";
}
```

How, though, would I access the userName property of the login element? I've tried `$entry->login['userName']`, which produces an error message "Cannot use object of type Zend_Gdata_Gapps_Extension_Login as array", and `$entry->login`, which I would have expected to work (I don't have to specify the "name" property of the nickname element, so why would I need to specify the userName property of login?) but that one throws this error: "Method Zend_Gdata_Gapps_Extension_Login::__toString() must not throw an exception".

So how do I access that property?

**EDIT**
I've also tried a nested loop through login (assuming there might be more than one per entry) like so:

```
$nicknames = $service->retrieveAllNicknames();
foreach ($nicknames->entries as $entry) {
  $nick = $entry->nickname;
  foreach ($entry->login as $loginName) {
    $login .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;".$loginName->userName;
  }
  echo "<p>".$login." - ". $nick."</p>";
}
```

That produces "Undefined variable: login in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/google_api/get_nicknames.php on line 29" over and over (one for each entry) where line 29 is the echo line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.gapps.html you can use this code:

```
$feed = $gdata->retrieveAllNicknames();

foreach ($feed as $nickname) {
    echo '  * ' . $nickname->nickname->name . ' => ' .
        $nickname->login->username . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a very helpful link, and one that google didn't return when I was searching.